# Pesky server error on Python web app

Tags: django, python-2.7, web, server-error

I've been having a problem with a website that I'm working on not attaching pictures to html emails. Thought I had it fixed but then every time someone tries to register on it I get a Server Error (500). I've only changed a couple of references so no idea what went wrong there, anyways error log is as follows:

```
2016-08-31 08:26:15,757 :Internal Server Error: /register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asranet/.virtualenvs/testenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/asranet/.virtualenvs/testenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "./register/views.py", line 14, in index
    form.save(commit=True)
  File "/home/asranet/.virtualenvs/testenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 451, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "./register/models.py", line 35, in save
    email_client(self, site_settings.site_name + "Conference Registration", "You are officially registered for AdWind 2017")
  File "./adWind/email_functionality.py", line 31, in email_client
    fp = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f), 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'./adWind/static/Images/asranetLogo.jpg'
```

I checked and the file is there. No idea how to proceed, could really use some help. Thank you in advance!

P.S. here's the code for email functionality:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
import os
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from reportlab.platypus.doctemplate import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Spacer
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from django.http import HttpResponse

try:
from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
from StringIO import StringIO


def email_client(self, subject, text):
# Send the client an email
html_content =                  render_to_string("../templates/baseTemplates/emailToUser.html", {'salutation':     self.salutation,
                                                                                'last_name':
                                                                                        self.last_name,
                                                                                'text_body': text})
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, 'Dear ' + self.salutation + ' ' +
                         self.last_name + '/n' + text,
                         'adwind@asranet.co.uk', [self.email], )
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.attach_file('/static/Images/asranetLogo.jpg')
msg.mixed_subtype = 'related'

f = '/static/Images/asranetLogo.jpg'
fp = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f), 'rb')
msg_img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msg_img.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(f))
msg.attach(msg_img)
msg.send(fail_silently=True)


def email_admin(self, subject, text, sorted_self):

styleSheet = getSampleStyleSheet()

# Send the admin a PDF of client details
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="clientDetails.pdf"'

string_buffer = StringIO()

new_pdf = []
header = Paragraph("AdWind Attendee Details", styleSheet['Heading1'])
new_pdf.append(header)

for element in sorted_self:
new_pdf.append(Paragraph(element[0], styleSheet['Heading3']))
new_pdf.append(Paragraph(element[1], styleSheet['BodyText']))
new_pdf.append(Spacer(1, 2))

doc = SimpleDocTemplate(string_buffer)
doc.build(new_pdf)
pdf = string_buffer.getvalue()
string_buffer.close()

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text, "adwind@asranet.co.uk",     ["adwind@asranet.co.uk"])
msg.attach(self.first_name + self.last_name + "adWind.pdf", pdf,     "application/pdf")
msg.send(fail_silently=True)
```

Comment: Please show the code of `email_functionality`.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman I've posted the code below (too big for a reply so had to "answer").

Comment: You should post it as an update to your question. Please ensure you have the indentation correct, as well.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just added the update, apologies about not indenting the original post

Answer (score 0):

In Django the static directory is usually under a module_name directory. I suggest changing your paths into a relative one:

```
msg.attach_file('static/[module_name]/Images/asranetLogo.jpg')
```

and

```
f = 'static/[module_name]/Images/asranetLogo.jpg'
```

Comment: yeah tried it yesterday but to no avail. That's the main problem with a Server Error 500 it doesn't really tell you anything..

Comment: Where is the image actually located ?

Comment: have a few projects runing, so that'll be  "adWind/static/Images/" (adWind being the project folder)